# jquery, selector, style

Tags: jquery, find

HI,

How can I add by jQuery, some class "test" just  to  what have style="display:none",

Output:

```
<tr style="display:none" class="test"></td></td></tr>
<tr></td></td></tr>
<tr style="display:none" class="test"></td></td></tr>>
<tr></td></td></tr>
```

Thanks

Comment: the question is... how can I add the class `test` to a tr that has `style="display:none"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the ":hidden" qualifier is sort-of what you want:

```
$('div:hidden').addClass('test');
```

That's a little flaky because ":hidden" does not just apply to elements with an explicit "display:none" style. If you really want it to be robust, it would be better to give your hidden elements some other class name (even if it doesn't have any CSS effect).  Then you could write:

```
$('div.testMe').addClass('test');
```

Comment: i love how jquery makes you better at css :-)

Comment: $('tr:hidden').addClass('test');

Answer (score 2):

```
$("tr").each(function(){
  if($(this).css("display") == "none")
      $(this).addClass("test");
});
```

Comment: The only one who answered the question +1

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
$(".test[style*=none]")
```

or

```
$(".test:hidden")
```

or (most accurate to your question)

```
$(".test").filter(function() { return $(this).css('display') == 'none'; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $('.test').hide();
});
```

Comment: $(function() {}) is equivalent to $(document).load(function {})

Comment: I actually use $(function() {}), but a lot of jQuery noobs don't know that syntax, so I used the more verbose syntax.

Answer (score 0):

or if you wanna alter its style .. use

```
$(function() {
    $('.test').css("display", "none");
});
```